# Varant box shows phpinfo() Only

Tags: laravel, vagrant, laravel-5, homestead

I use vagrant for my Laravel 5 application.

I only get "phpinfo()" page if i try to access my second domain.

1.homestead.app [Working]

2.lshop.app [show "phpinfo()"]

My homestead.yaml is,

```
 ---
 ip: "192.168.10.10"
 memory: 2048
 cpus: 1
 provider: virtualbox

 authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

 keys:
- ~/.ssh/id_rsa

 folders:
- map: ~/Code
  to: /home/vagrant/Code

 sites:
- map: homestead.app
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/laravel/public

- map: l5shop.app
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/lshop/public

  databases:
- homestead
```

What is Wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I get solution:

I just go and change the host file {/etc/hosts}.

Now its working fine.